# Angular.js ng-style won't bind value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a problem with angularjs and even after research I just couldn't find where I'm wrong.

I need to recalculate the css value "left" for an element. I'm using the 'ng-style' directive and a method that will return an object with the css value. Thats - afaik - what I have to do. But when I update the value, it wont update the style.

*ng-bind usage:*

```
<div ng-style="getCssShiftObject()">
```

*method to create object*

```
$scope.getCssShiftObject =function(){
   return {'left':this.cssShift+'px'};
};
```

*method to change the object*

```
 $scope.nextPosition = function(){
     if((this.currentPosition+1) <= this.maxPosition){
        this.currentPosition = this.currentPosition+1;
        this.cssShift = (this.currentPosition*this.slideSize)*-1;
    }
    return this.currentPosition;
 };
```

It will update at another place in the content when I use it like that:

`{{getCssShiftObject()}}`

I hope you can give mit a hit, thanks for your time!

Comment: who and when calls `$scope.nextPosition` ?

Comment: can you add fiddle or plunker?

Comment: It's called by an ng-click directive

Comment: i don't see any problem: http://jsfiddle.net/VeFfJ/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for your time! I solved the Problem with the input from Cherniv, but I'm not sure how. I changed the way I create the values. Now it's working.

```
$scope.calcCssShift = function(){
  this.cssShift = ($scope.currentPosition * $scope.slideSize)*-1;
};

$scope.getCssShiftObject =function(){
   return {'left':$scope.cssShift+'px'};
};

$scope.nextPosition = function(){
   if((this.currentPosition+1) <= this.maxPosition){
      $scope.currentPosition = this.currentPosition+1;
      $scope.calcCssShift();
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 5):

I came across a similar problem. I was trying to use ngStyle to load a background image, but if the variable in an expression is not immediately available (which might be the case if it's part of a resource promise), it won't work.

To address this, I created my own ngStyle directive that addresses this issue. Hopefully this is better than creating functions for every single scenario where you want to use ngStyle in this way.

```
app.directive("myStyle", function (){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            var el   = element[0],
                attr = el.getAttribute('style');

            el.setAttribute('style', attr);

            // We need to watch for changes in the style in case required data is not yet ready when compiling
            attrs.$observe('style', function (){
                attr = el.getAttribute('style');

                if(attr)
                {
                    el.setAttribute('style', attr);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then, you can use it this way:

```
<a my-style style="background-image: url('{{promise.myImage}}')"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the style attribute. My binding was not working in some browsers, especially IE. I solved it by using **ng-attr-style**="{{yourBindingExpression}}".

Read more about ng-attr interpolation at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation